# Word for the opposite of a mistake -- an intentional act that goes against what you are trained to do (or even the law)

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Not just a benign mistake, but an intentional act that goes against what you are trained to do or even the law.

For example, a police officer who arrests someone for an untenable reason.

Comment: The opposite of a mistake is an *intentional act*.

Comment: Hello, welcome to English Language and Usage SE! The goal of this site is to provide detailed answers to questions about English. Because of this, questions are expected to provide detail and context to make it easier for other users to write good answers. Please edit your question after looking over the [question checklist for single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info). (Also, the word "opposite" is not very precise, so it's difficult for me to understand what you actually mean by "the opposite of a mistake" without more information).

Comment: Thanks for editing to add more information! I just edited to change the title as well so that people aren't confused before they see the body of the question. I would advise editing this further according to the instructions for asking this sort of question that are given in the "single word requests" tag wiki.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The keyword here is "willful." There are two common terms:

[**willful violation**](http://definitions.uslegal.com/w/willful-violation/):

> A willful violation, in the context of workplace safety, is the most serious violation under the laws administered by the federal Occupational Safety and Health Administration (OSHA).  It occurs when an employer knows that a hazardous situation exists and makes no reasonable attempt to eliminate it, commits such a violation intentionally and knowingly.

and

[**willful misconduct**](http://definitions.uslegal.com/w/willful-misconduct/):

> Willful misconduct generally means a knowing violation of a reasonable and uniformly enforced rule or policy. It means intentionally doing that which should not be done or intentionally failing to do that which should be done, knowing that injury to a person will probably result or recklessly disregarding the possibility that injury to a person may result. The term is applied in various legal contexts, such as employment and, torts, and public offices.

"Willful violations," as mentioned in the definition above, most commonly refer to actions by an employer that knowingly endanger the health or safety of employees, but it can also apply to violation of other laws and regulations.

"Willful misconduct" (which seems more pertinent to the thrust of your question) refers to actions by an individual that go against laws, policies, etc. within the context of their employment or duty.

(Both definitions quoted from http://definitions.uslegal.com/)

Comment: *Willfulness* also plays a role in the enforcement policy of the U.S. Nuclear Regulatory Commission, along with "careless disregard". Both generally  lead to "escalated enforcement". +1 for *willful*.

Answer (score 3):

How about *abuse of power*? While not single word, it is an idiomatic phrase that aligns well with your question. Specifically:

> An *abuse of power*, is "not just a benign mistake, but an intentional
>   act that goes against what you are trained to do or even the law".
>
> A police officer who arrests someone for an untenable reason is
>   clearly *abusing his or her power*.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abuse_of_power):

> *Abuse of power*, in the form of "malfeasance in office" or "official misconduct," is the commission of an unlawful act, done in an official
>   capacity, which affects the performance of official duties.

The Wikipedia reference devote a section to police officers.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a ***malicious** act*.

From uslegal.com:

> [Malicious Law & Legal Definition](http://definitions.uslegal.com/m/malicious/):
> **Malicious** means substantially certain to cause injury, being deliberately harmful or spiteful, without just cause or excuse. There
> are different types of malicious acts which are considered offenses.
> For example, malicious prosecution, malicious mistake, malicious
> killing etc.
>
> A ***malicious** act* is an intentional, wrongful act
> performed against another without legal justification or excuse.

Black's Law Dictionary:

> [What is MALICIOUS ACT?](http://thelawdictionary.org/malicious-act/)
>
> a term referring to doing an intentionally wrong act.